# Chutes and Ladders Game Random Placement Issue

Tags: java, methods, random

I'm a student, working on a Chutes and Ladders game. I'm using methods to determine how many chutes and ladders should be placed on the game board. I'm specifying 10 for each in main using parameters but I keep getting anywhere from 6 to 11 placed across the board.

Is there something going on with the two methods interfering with each other?

Or is there a problem with the way I set up the for loops for random placement?

I'm new to this site, please let me know if you need more clarification, I didn't want to place the whole program in here. Thanks.

```
//main
                  ChutesAndLadders cl = new ChutesAndLadders();
                  cl.setBoard(new String[100]);
                  cl.makeChutes(10);
                  cl.makeLadders(10);

//methods
            public String [] board;
            private int chutes, ladders;
            public int position;
            public Random rand = new Random();


        //set board
                    public void setBoard(String [] n){
                        board = n;
                        for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++)
                            board[i] = "   ";
                    }
        //set and place chutes
                    public void makeChutes(int n){
                        chutes = n;
                        for(int i = 0; i <= chutes; i++)                    
                            board[rand.nextInt(board.length)] = "C" + chutes;

                    }
        //set and place ladders
                    public void makeLadders(int n){
                        ladders = n;
                            int lcell = 0; 
                        for(int i = 0; i <= ladders; i++)
                                 board[rand.nextInt(board.length)] = "L" + ladders;
```

Comment: I upvoted Mike Clark's answer. I suggest that you have methods `placeChute` and `placeLadder` that include a check that there is nothing already at the location.

Comment: With a situation like this, you're bound to run into the Birthday Paradox (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem).  In case you wanted some light reading. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, you wrote:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= chutes; i++)                    
    board[rand.nextInt(board.length)] = "C" + chutes;
```

The assignment statement in the loop will run chutes+1 times.  (Eleven times in your case.)  [Use `i < chutes` instead.] This is the same in your ladders code.  This explains why you might have up to 11 chutes or ladders when the code is done running.

Secondly, you do not take care to prevent the same space being assigned a chute or ladder multiple times.  `rand.nextInt(board.length)` is not guaranteed to generate unique values each time it is run (otherwise it wouldn't really be random.)  This explains why you may not see as many as 11 chutes and ladders when the code is done running.

To make this clearer, put a constant value in there:

```
for(int i = 0; i < chutes; i++)                    
    board[11] = "C" + chutes;
```

and notice that you end up with one chute (at space eleven)--unless the ladder code overwrites it with a ladder.

Hope that helps.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

At first glance my guess is that you are winding up with overlapping entries.  Because you generate a random placement and don't check to see if there is already a chute or ladder there, you are likely winding up with overlaps.

It should be fairly straightforward to generate the random position and then check if there is something there prior to placement.  If a collision is found, just generate another random and repeat until you can place it.

Also, as an aside, it is always a good practice to avoid for loops and if statements without curly braces.  It is very easy to add a second like to the block and wonder why it is not executing as part of the block.

Answer (score 1):

Your for loops have an inclusive upper limit check, `0 .. 10` yields 11 entries.

Like Mike said, the lower number of results are due to collisions, you can prevent those by setting up the board by filling it with the elements needed and then shuffling the board to get the end result, something like:

```
public void setupBoard(String [] n, int nrLadders, int nrChutes){
    board = n;
    int index = 0;

    while (index < board.length && 0 < nrLadders--) {
        board[index++] = "L" + nrLadders;
    }

    while (index < board.length && 0 < nrChutes--) {
        board[index++] = "C" + nrChutes;
    }

    while (index < board.length) {
        board[index++] = "   ";
    }

    board = Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(board)).toArray(new String[board.length]);
}
```

This is like creating a deck of cards containing a number of ladder cards, a number of chute cards, a larger number of empty spot cards and shuffling that deck to get the game board.